# как переводится "would have been"?

Tags: грамматика

Как переводится "would have been working" : В конце года, исполнилось бы 12 лет, как он работает \ работал \ работал бы в этой фирме, но его уволили \ но он был уволен?

Comment: К концу года он _проработал бы_ на фирме 12 лет, но был уволен.

Answer (score 2):

"Исполнилось бы 12 лет, как он работает в этой фирме" is the most universal one, "исполнилось бы 12 лет, как он работал" can be applicable if narrator talks about events that happen in the past, "работал бы" is ungrammatical in this particular case, though in colloquial speech repetitive "бы" is quite frequent.

However! It worth to know that de-facto in the overwhelming majority of cases "исполнилось бы" is used only for the age, like "ему исполнилось бы 23", "ей исполнилось бы теперь восемнадцать лет" etc. Have one say something like what you intend to say, they'd rather use something like:

- В конце года было б 12 лет, как он работает в фирме
- В конце года будет 12 лет как он работает в фирме (if we are talking about "now").

Comment: It seems to me that "исполнилось" is not used only for age. Next sentences from [link](https://znanija.com/task/28165676) seems correct for me. This may be applied to any anniversary (годовщине).

Comment: @elena_m grammatically definitely however if you google usages you'd be surprise who much it's used exclusively for age.